# My balance of a address on my wallet RPC does not change

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

I am currently using Monero RPC with the stagenet.
I have two addresses.
Using a Monero stagenet faucet, I received 10 XMR, and everything works because my balance for the first address is 10,000,000,000,000.
Now, I have sent 0.063 XMR to my second address, and it also appears in its balance (61,324,974,324).

However, the balance (and unlocked_balance) of my first address remains at 10,000,000,000,000.
Is this normal?"